# Trouble with loops for nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following relationship:

```
store.rb -> has_many :products
product.rb -> belongs_to :store
```

routes.rb

```
resources :stores do
  resources :products
end
```

What I'm trying to do right now is create a loop that displays ALL products with the stores they belong to, so that when I click on the anchor tag, it takes me to the page of the product in the correct store, and not another store like the following code does for me:

```
<ul>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li>
      <a href="<%= url_for([@store, product]) %>"><%= product.name %></a>  
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The aforementioned code generates the following urls for me:

- stores/walmart/products/large-gun
- stores/walmart/products/fruits

instead of

- stores/gun-shop/products/large-gun
- stores/walmart/products/fruits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supplying the same store for every link so that won't work.

Try this:

```
<a href="<%= url_for([product.store, product]) %>"><%= product.name %></a>
```

The variable `@store` is apparently Walmart.  If you don't change it, it will remain Walmart.

Comment: I'm trying to display this list on the home page of my website though. How do you suggest I setup the variables in the controller?

Comment: @imjp Meaning what? Keep the list of products as-is, and show each product's store as in the answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I thought he put @store.product instead of product.store. Thank you David.